# android design pattern for multiple pages: multiple activities of multiple xmls?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-layout

My app needs to have multiple screen e.g. one login page then another page that displays a list of items and then one that displays details of the the selected item. I want to know what is the general/accepted practice in such cases? I suspect it would be to have multiple layouts but how do I store which item has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass it between the activities, there are various ways to do this. The easiest for simple items is to pass them in the Intent

On Activity A:

```
...
intent.putExtra("selectedItem", "1");
startActivity(intent);
```

On Activity B:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String item = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
```

Comment: There are a bunch of these extras for all types of variables.

Comment: is there a reason behind choosing this? I mean we could also have just one activity and switch b/w layouts.

Comment: One good reason could be cleaner code. When the layouts get big , the activity can get bloated and hard to follow. Also, you can share activities with other apps or easily re-use inside your app.

Comment: There is no real advantage in switching layouts, in fact its much more confusing, you are going to need to link the different layouts to different code, so on every Activity method you will need some sort of way to keep track of which layout is loaded and then  do a bunch of if statements to figure out which code to run. Its a terrible idea now that I think about it.